# Passing environment variables to `docker-compose` when using ecs context

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, amazon-ecs

I am trying to use the new ecs context that the latest docker cli exposes. When I create the context using `docker context create ecs my_context`, I select the use environment variables method (the recommended way), how now matter how I try to call `docker compose`, it always returns the message `context requires credentials to be passed as environment variables`. Searching for this message in google returns nothing :/

I have tried passing using the `-e` and `--environment` flags, I have tried with a `.env` file, and the `--env-file` flag.

```
docker --context my_ecs compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXX -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXXXX -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=XXXXXXXX up
```

If I don't use the environment variable method, it hits another known (frustrating) bug, whereby it uses the wrong aws region, even though the context is setup with the correct region. I feel the environment variable option would resolve that, if I could get it to see the environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it works passing the variables during the `docker compose up` command. The way it works is that you export the access key ID, secret access key and region variables in your shell and then you create the docker context by pointing to the variables [as shown here](https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#create-aws-context).

You can do that interactively by launching `docker context create ecs myecscontext` and then picking `AWS environment variables` or you can just run `docker context create ecs myecscontext --from-env`.

And yes the region bug is annoying, if [this](https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/1056) is what you are referring to.

Comment: Yep that’s the region issue :S there’s no export option in windows shell, which is probably where I’m falling down

Comment: OMG Windows ... :) ... this is a 15 years throw back. Kidding aside....I have never used it on Windows but I assume a `SET` (instead of `EXPORT`) would do?

Comment: Yea I have tried `SET` many times, and even manually adding ENV variables, but it doesn't pick them up. Interesting thing I found out though, the `docker-compose` cli automatically picks up variables in `.env` files, without even specifying a file with the `--env-file` flag, seems like another bug :S However for ecs integration, I need to use the `docker` cli with the new `compose` option... I don't believe it is picking up the `.env` file the same, otherwise I probably wouldn't be having this problem :D

Comment: Can confirm that using `docker compose -f docker-compose.build.yml build` also picks up a `.env` at the same location by default

Answer (score 3):

Google search lead me to this post, (I am not using Windows but aws cloud9 IDE,)
I could get rid of the message `context requires credentials to be passed as environment variables` by passing dummy values to the environment vars, it goes like this.

```
$ docker context create ecs myecscontext 
? Create a Docker context using: AWS environment variables
Successfully created ecs context "myecscontext"
$ docker context use myecscontext                                                                    
myecscontext
$ docker context ls
context requires credentials to be passed as environment variables
$ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=dummy AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=dummy AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=dummy docker context ls     
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT               KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default             moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                         swarm
myecscontext *      ecs                 credentials read from environment                                                             
$ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=dummy AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=dummy AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=dummy docker context use default
default
$ docker context ls
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT               KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default *           moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                         swarm
myecscontext        ecs                 credentials read from environment                                                             
$ docker context rm myecscontext
myecscontext
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to resource my terminal with `source ~/.bash_profile` because I was using `.bashrc` as my source and this did not have my environment variables in it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify and export environmental variables on Linux or MacOs with [Environment variables to configure the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html):

- `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE`
- `export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY`
- `export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2`

Later, you can see the options with this command:

```
docker context create ecs --help
```

**Description**: Create a context for Amazon ECS

**Usage**:
docker context create ecs CONTEXT [flags]

**Flags**:

- `--access-keys string`   :Use AWS access keys from file
- `--description string`   :Description of the context
- `--from-env`:Use AWS environment variables for profile, or credentials and region
- `-h`, `--help`: Help for ecs
- `--local-simulation` :Create context for ECS local simulation endpoints
- `--profile string`  :Use an existing AWS profile

**Answer**: `docker context create ecs CONTEXT --from-env`

Answer (score 0):

I've handled this situation by setting environment variables. You can use [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) for this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).